# Using DbContext Set<T>() instead of exposing on the context

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext

Are there any differences when doing the following:

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

versus using the `Set<T>` method of the context:

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
}

var db = new UsersContext();
var users = db.Set<User>();
```

These effectively do the same thing, giving me a set of Users, but are there any big differences other than you are not exposing the set through a property?

Comment: @abatishchev http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696521(v=vs.103).aspx Nope there is a Set<T> method

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `Users` property is added for convenience, so you don't need to remember what all of your tables are and what the corresponding class is for it, you can use Intellisense to see all of the tables the context was designed to interact with.  The end result is functionally equivalent to using `Set<T>`.

Comment: Users could be only one instance while in context, i am wondering about Set method, return single instance also?

Comment: Which one do you want? You could use System.Linq.Dynamic. db.Set<User>().Single("Id = @0", someId); as long as the primary key is Id on the User object or any you query.

Answer (score 9):

You get a benefit with the former method when using Code-First migrations, as new entities will be detected as such automatically.  Otherwise, I'm quite certain they are equivalent.

Comment: I did not think of migrations!

Answer (score 5):

This is how I set my generic dbSet, works just fine

```
DbContext context = new MyContext();
DbSet<T> dbSet = context.Set<T>();
```

It is the generic version of something more explicit, such as

```
DbContext context = new MyContext();
DbSet<User> dbSet = context.Set<User>();
```

Either way, they are the same (when `T` is `User`)

Comment: Err...okay? I understand how it works. I wanted to know what the differences / limitations are.

Comment: @Dismissile - No limitations or differences, except that you might save yourself some repeating code by using the generic definition and passing in the type.

Comment: Set<> should be return always single instance to tell no limitations or differences, right?

Comment: Reviewing the decompiled source, the DbSet will be the same instance per instance of a DbContext (e.g., if you call context.Set<T>() multiple times, you get the same reference to the same DbSet, assuming "context" never changed instances). This is done in the InternalContext inside the DbContext (it keeps an internal Dictionary using the Type as a key).

Answer (score 3):

One difference is that the Set method takes any type include non entities and it won't throw exceptions, only returning an empty set of that type. So you could mess up if you typed the wrong class name.

Comment: both of them do the samething thing,  context.Set<T>(); and  context.Set<Users>(), thie first one is generic, the second one if for Users entities.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some difference.
Let me use the example as in the question.
Assume i want to do a Any based on User.FirstName and User.LastName (User table has more fields)

Method1: `UsersContext.Users.Any(u => u.FirstName.ToLower() == userObj.FirstName &&  u.LastName.ToLower() == userObj.LastName);`

Method2: `(UsersContext.Set(typeof(User)) as IQueryable<User>).Any(u => u.FirstName.ToLower() == userObj.FirstName &&  u.LastName.ToLower() == userObj.LastName);`

I checked in sql profiler the query fired in Method1 is:

```
    exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[User] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (((LOWER([Extent1].[FirstName])) = (LOWER(@p__linq__0))) AND ((LOWER([Extent1].[LastName])) = @p__linq__1)
)) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[User] AS [Extent2]
    WHERE (((LOWER([Extent2].[FirstName])) = (LOWER(@p__linq__0))) AND ([Extent2].[LastName] = @p__linq__1)
)) THEN cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1]
FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]',@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__1 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'jack',@p__linq__1=N'saw'
```

From Method2:

```
    SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
[Extent1].[Email] AS [Email], 
.......other fields......
FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
```

The table has 40000 records and Method1 takes around 20 ms while Method2 takes around 3500 ms.

Comment: Set can take a generic parameter. Try Set<User>().Any( ... )

Comment: @Dismissile I tried Set<User>().Any() and it has the same behavior.

Comment: You are doing something very weird then, because all three methods produce the same exact query for me.

Comment: @Dismissile you are right. I figured-out the weird part. When in case of Method2 i.e. Set<User>().Any( ... ), i am passing the expression like `ValidationMethod<User>(u => u.FirstName.ToLower() == userObj.FirstName &&  u.LastName.ToLower() == userObj.LastName)` this intern would do `Set<User>().Any( .. expression passed as param.. ) ` not sure about the exact reason. Still looking for it. Will update.

Comment: am tracking the issue [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c78b7e9c-eff0-4274-a958-3f0e33d9ad8d/difference-in-using-dbcontextentity-property-vs-using-via-dbcontextset-method?forum=adodotnetentityframework&prof=required)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such difference between two approaches except that `Set<User>()` is more suitable for implementing data access patterns like `Repository` pattern because of the generic nature of the `Set<T>()` method.

Comment: Yeah I understand where they have their uses for a generic repository, but I was curious if there were any downsides to it.