# How the Set<T>() method works in DbContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5

The Entity Framework documentations tells us to add DbSets to a DBContext during code first approach. Like this:

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; } 
}
```

if I call the Set method on an instance of BloggingContext, would it return the property Blogs?

Given

```
BloggingContext ctx = new BloggingContext()
```

will

```
ctx.Blogs ;
```

and

```
ctx.Set<Blog> ;
```

return the same object?

Comment: This has been already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13710883/using-dbcontext-sett-instead-of-exposing-on-the-context

Comment: @AntonyFrancis I read that answer but didn't clear my doubts. What I am asking is if I do ctx.Blogs.remove(i) will that also be removing i  from whatever ctx.Set<Blog>() returns. Does Set<T> look for properties of type DbSet<T> and returns if found?

Comment: Yes. It will. `Public DbSet <Blog> Blogs` is a nice shorthand to access Blogs entity instead of calling  `ctx.Set <Blog>`.