# Any Point to the DbSet Property Name?

Tags: entity-framework

```
public DbSet<Lecture> Lectures{ get; set; }
```

Does the property name here matter at all? It seems that if I want to use the model, I use "Lecture". The generated table is just a plural of whatever is in `<>`, e.g., if I understand correctly, I can change "Lectures" to "Leprechauns" and my table will still be called "Lectures" based on `<Lecture>` and I will use `context.Lectures` to select from it. Does the property name have any point?

I didn't find the answers in this [tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/dbsetclass.aspx) or on msdn.

Edit: Upon further testing - the db table name is based on the model name in the angle brackets, but to actually select from the db (in the C# code), you use the property name specified in DbSet propertyName. Still would like to hear how this works in detail.

Comment: The property is used to access the associated `DbSet`, but its name doesn't affect anything in the mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework builds a model of the database, where each class/model represents an [entity type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee382837(v=vs.100).aspx), and each `DbSet` represents a set of entities of a single type. When you declare a `DbSet<T>` property in your `DbContext`, that tells EF to include the class of type `T` as one of the entity types, and it automatically includes any other connected types (e.g. navigation properties) in the object graph as well.

All this to say, the name of the property itself probably doesn't matter. In fact, you could use the [Fluent API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617) to add entity types as well, not declare any `DbSet` properties if you wanted, in which case you'd use [`context.Set<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13710883/using-dbcontext-sett-instead-of-exposing-on-the-context) to retrieve the `DbSet`s. The properties are really just for convenience.

Maybe this is helpful as well: *https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592675.aspx*

Answer (score 0):

`DbSet` corresponds to a table or view in your database, So you will be using your `DbSet`'s to get access, create, update, delete and modify your table data.
By the way you can remove the convention:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{    
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

Comment: I understand what DbSet does - I am asking if the property name is used anywhere, or if it all derives from the type (which, I assume, has to be "DbSet<nameOfYourModel>"

Answer (score 0):

The property name matters. The EF translates the name of the property into the name of the table. If the property name is not the same with the table name you'll get an error. Unless you specifically tell the builder the name of the table like this:

```
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Lecture> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("License");
    }
```