# Code First to Existing Database, Context.Set<T> not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to implement a generic repository in a solution using Code first to an existing database. When i try to do a Context.Set I get an error stating that the "Entity Type is not a part of the model for the current context". What am i missing?

```
public partial class CPContext : DbContext
{
    public CPContext()
        : base("name=CPContext")
    {

    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

    }
}
```

Model:

```
[Table("Core.Tenant")]
public partial class Tenant : IEntity
{
}
```

Usage:

```
var context =  new CPContext();
var dbSet = context.Set<Tenant>();
var results = dbSet.ToList();
```

This throws an error -  Entity Type is not a part of the model for the current context

I was able to get it to wok by changing the OnModelCreating event of the Context like so -

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().ToTable("Core.Tenant");
    }
```

But i am not sure why i need to do the above when using Data Annotations for Table names? Completely lost here

Comment: if "Core" is the namespace, you might want to use this annotation `[Table("Tenant", Schema="Core")]`

Comment: The problem come from Partial keyword and not from data annotation and you have to use the DbSet exacatly as described in the @KiNeTiC answer!

Comment: @BassamAlugili It works with Fluent Mapping  without declaring the DbSet's , You mentioned Partial -  how does the Context being partial affect this scenario?

Comment: Fleunt API: I know it is working but for me it is a bad practice and in only in a few use cases you can use this approach.  Forget about the partial ,  the problem when you configure your table with Code first then you have to define your entity in your DbContext, otherwise will get an 'System.InvalidOperationException'  because EF ensure/check that the entity is exists in the DbContext or not.

Comment: example for a generic repo: public class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : Entity and the entity is the base class for all your entities. and +1 for @KiNeTiC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a DbSet in your context.

```
public partial class CPContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Tenant> Tenants { get; set;}

    public CPContext()
        : base("name=CPContext")
    {

    }
```

That's why annotation mapping is not working.  EF has no way to know it has to map that class.

Comment: I thought the context.Set<T> can be used instead of declaring DbSets. As in the following situation - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13710883/using-dbcontext-sett-instead-of-exposing-on-the-context

Comment: Oh if you're using fluent mapping, it will work without the DbSet, no doubt about it.

Comment: That's my understanding, but I could be wrong.  I don't have Visual Studio on my home computer, so I can't test this.