# In Memory Database with.Net Core not adding data to entity collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, xunit.net, entity-framework-core

I am creating xunit test with EF Core 2.0.0 and InMemory 2.0.0. I noticed that the entities are not being added in the context. However it is being added at context..Local

Below is the snippet of the code

```
 public UnitOfWorkTest()
 {
   _appointment = new Appointment
   {
      AppointmentType     = AppointmentTypes.EyeTest,
      AppProgress         = Appointment.Confirmed,
      BranchIdentifier    = "MEL",
      DateAdded           = DateTime.Now,
      Duration            = 30,
      Resid               = "KAI",
    };

  }
public MyDbContext InitContext()
{
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>()
                 .UseInMemoryDatabase("Add_writes_to_database")
                 .Options;

    return new MyDbContext(options);
 }

 public async Task UnitOfWork_Transaction_Test()
 {
     using (var context = InitContext())
     {
          using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(context))
          {
              context.Appointment.Add(_appointment);
              await unitOfWork.Commit();

              Assert.True(context.Appointment.Local.Count == 1);
           }
      }
 }
```

### Unit of Work

```
public sealed class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private IDbContext _dbContext;
    public UnitOfWork(IDbContext context)
    {

        _dbContext = context;
    }
    public async Task<int> Commit()
    {
        // Save changes with the default options
        return await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_dbContext != null)
            {
                _dbContext.Dispose();
                _dbContext = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### IDbContext

```
 public interface IDbContext : IDisposable
    {
        DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
        EntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class;
        EntityEntry Entry(object entity);
        Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
    }
```

`context.Appointment` always return empty list/null but I can see the added entity in `context.Appointment.Local`

Any idea why this happens? How do I get the entity added in Appointment collection and not in Appointment.Local collection?

Comment: Can you show your UnitOfWork class and what does your unitOfWork.Commit() ?

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve].

Comment: @hugorgor I have edited the question

Comment: can you remove the "using" surrounding the "new UnitOfWork"?

Comment: still having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

After this line `context.Appointment.Add(_appointment);` try to save changes in your context `context.SaveChanges()`.I hope it will help.

Comment: He is doing this in the `unitOfWork.Commit()` part. I see that this is your first answer, so mistakes are possible, but please in the future, before answering, make sure that you require all the information needed, so that your answer can be as accurate as possible.

Answer (score 0):

In-memory database is faking a *test double*. Your current test relies on the **implementation details** of "`DbSet<T>` properties" within this test double.

I think implementation details is the answer to **why** [`Set<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.set) works inplace:

```
Assert.True(context.Set<Appointment>().Count == 1);
```

`DbSet<T>` properties are there for convenience, rather than to implement data access. It is not even obligatory to have - all of - them in the context class (until you provide *navigation properties* in entity classes).

You can also check: [Using DbContext Set<T>() instead of exposing on the context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13710883/using-dbcontext-sett-instead-of-exposing-on-the-context) for clarification.