# DbContext.set() cannot create a DbSet for entity because this type is not included in the model for the context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I am using **EF Core**. I am using `DbContext.Set()` method but it is giving me the error - "Cannot create a DbSet for 'MediaDate' because this type is not included in the model for the context.'"

Below is my code:

```
var context = new GoldentaurusContext();
DbSet<MediaDate> set = context.Set<MediaDate>();
mediaDateList = set.FromSql("[dbo].[sp_GetMediaDate]")
                .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.DateText, Value = x.DateValue })
                .ToList();
```

The MediaDate class:

```
public class MediaDate
{
    public string DateText { get; set; }
    public string DateValue { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Why it is requiring me to add the **MediaDate** class to the **DbContext** class?

Please help what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried another way of creating a `DbSet<T>` instance external to `DbContext`?  What you're trying to do is probably better achieved using Dapper.

Comment: I'm going to execute SQL query and StoredProcedure and in both case getting same error message. Any idea on this?

Comment: @yogihosting - Can you post your solution?

Comment: @RajuPaladiya any solution found? stuck in same issue while executing SQL Query / Stored Procedure

Answer (score 6):

Your DB Context class should be like below.

```
 public partial class DatabaseContext : DbContext
   {

    public DatabaseContext (string ConnectionString) : base(new DbContextOptionsBuilder().UseSqlServer(ConnectionString).Options)
    {

    }  
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Query<MediaData>();            
    }
```

Add your models in the DatabaseContext using model builder.
This is how I have resolved this isssue

Comment: `Query<>` is obsolete in .NET Core 3. Use `modelBuilder.Entity<MediaData>().HasNoKey();`

Comment: if you have to add all models in dbcontext what is the purpose of generic set?

Answer (score 6):

For EF in DotNet Core 3.1+ make sure you add your non-table entity to the `OnModelCreating` override on your `DbContext` and call `.HasNoKey()` on the fluent API.  This will allow you to call a stored procedure using `DataContext.Set<MediaData>().FromSqlRaw("dbo.MyStoredProc")` and return your entity list.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<MediaData>().HasNoKey();
}
```

Comment: HasNoKey() is specific to this example and isn't required to map the entity without creating a table, in case someone was wondering. Thanks for this answer.

Comment: Defining `HasNoKey()` for the Db set resolves the issue, BUT it makes EF migration to generate table create for it, which is annoying

Comment: I was getting the feeling that the keyless nature of the model was the issue, but I'm in .NET 6 and the model is annotated as `[Keyless]`. And the query was working when I called it from a different location!

Answer (score 1):

A simple DatabaseContext would look like this:

```
using YourProject.Model;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace YourProject.Data
{
    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DatabaseContext() :
            base("name=YourDatabase")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<MediaData> MediaDates{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

You always need to include your models in the DatabaseContext to create the DbSets. Make sure you've declared the right namespaces and imported the right ones.

Comment: Why I have to add my MediaDate model to DatabaseContext? The purpose of Set is to use any model that are not added to DatabaseContext.??

Answer (score 1):

First, you should introduce your model (MediaDate) to DbContext.
add a `DbSet<MediaDate>` property to your context:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<MediaDate> MediaDates { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: No set() makes runtime dbset see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13710883/using-dbcontext-sett-instead-of-exposing-on-the-context