# How get Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>> generic

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I had the following code and I want to replace the Department type for a generic type...

I would do like to replace...

```
Expression.Lambda<Func<Department, bool>>(body, param)
```

by..

```
 Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param)
```

I know that I must use reflection, but all I have is a domain model class boxed as object.

I could get the object and his type name but I am having hard to replace the hard coded type Department by a generic type.

I can't convert method `Exists` to `Exists<T>` because I don't know what `<T>` is at the time of calling the method. I only have the object.

```
public bool Exists(object id, object source, Type type)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(type, "e");
    var body = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, "Id", Expression.Constant(id));
    var where = Expression.Lambda<Func<Department, bool>>(body, param);

    var context = new DataContext();

    var dbSet = context.Set<Department>();

    return dbSet.AsNoTracking().Any(where);
}
```

For the dbset case I tried the following code

```
public static IQueryable<object> Set (this DbContext context, Type type)
{
 return IQueryable<object>)context.GetType().GetMethod("Set")?.MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(context, null);
}
```

and replace...

```
var dbSet = context.Set<Department>();
```

by

```
var dbSet = context.Set(type);
```

It seems to work, I got the right dbset but there are some issues with the where clause that gives some run time errors.

What I am trying to achieve is avoid EF Core to do client side evaluation. I.e.

```
Any(e => e.ToString == id.ToString())
```

this will work but will perform an undesirable client side evaluation.

Comment: `Any(e => e.ToString == id.ToString())`? That doesn't compile, and when it would, it wouldn't be a client-side operation at all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using DbContext Set<T>() instead of exposing on the context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13710883/using-dbcontext-sett-instead-of-exposing-on-the-context)

Comment: If all of  your entities have an Id, you might as well make the models inherit from an interface so you don't have to build expression each time.  If some of your entities don't have an Id you should probably just filter by the PK instead

Answer (score 3):

> I can't convert method `Exists` to `Exists<T>` because I don't know what `<T>` is at the time of calling the method. I only have the `object`.

That is where generics would help with the generation of the dynamic lambda expression.

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class muckingabout
{
    public bool Exists<T>(T myentity) where T: MyEntity
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        //e =>
        var param = Expression.Parameter(type, "e");
        //e => e.Id    
        var property = Expression.Property(param, "Id");
        var value = Expression.Constant(myentity.Id);
        //e => e.Id == myentity.Id
        var body = Expression.Equal(property, value);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);

        using (var context = new DbContext())
        {
           var dbSet = context.Set<T>();
           return dbSet.AsNoTracking().Any(lambda);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect explanation for me. Thanks